# Speeding up of filtering rows in a huge matrix of size 100Mx10K

Tags: python, bigdata

I am using Dask to filter rows based on a simple parameter that reflects percentage of the top occurring (or most frequent) string in every row. The current implementation is time consuming on data of 100M rows and 10K columns, and I am trying to see if it can be further sped up. The code I am using is given below and I would appreciate any suggestion towards improvement:

```
def retention(row):
    min_retention = 90.0
    return (100.0 * Counter(row).most_common(1)[0][1] / len(row)) > min_retention

fil_df = df[df.apply(retention, axis=1, meta=(None, 'bool'))]
```

PS: All columns are strings.

Comment: I have only worked with pandas, so I might be wrong, but in pandas, `apply` is supposed to be quite slow. If vectorized methods are available (probably the case here), you shouldn't use `apply`. Second, `Counter` like in `collections.Counter`? That looks suspicious, too. You can get the most common value with `mode`. 
Third, isn't `len(row)` constant (equal to `len(df.columns)`)? You seem to compute it over and over again.

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed `collections.Counter`. I assumed `row` would be passed internally as some list/array so `len` would be inexpensive. Did not know of `mode`, I would check that too. (Perhaps might first store `row` as a list and work on that.) Thank you for these pointers. The `apply` function runs in parallel well as seen through the UI. But would like to know if a better alternative is available.

Comment: It looks like the only operation that has to be computed row-wise is getting the most common value, so it makes sense to separate the other steps from it. Once you have the most common values (with `apply` if you can't find another solution), you can do something like `100 * the_column / len(df.columns) > 90` which should be super fast.

Comment: Actually it is to find the normalized frequency of the most common value to filter, ie, `row.count(statistics.mode(row))/len(row)`, but I get the point. Thank you.